# jalali datepicker not working properly when using in more than one place in html

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Here I say if clicked on any days in calendar, to set the value in jalali_back_date input.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.datepicker-tablemonthgrid tr td', function() {
  $parent = $(this).parents('.calender');
  $prev = $parent.prev();
  date = $prev.children('[name^="jalali_"]').val();
  $prev.children('span').text(date);
  $parent.slideUp();
});
$(".calender").datepicker();

And here I have got the `$(this)` to set each date for it's related jalali_* input.

altField: $(this).prev().children('[name="jalali_' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]'),
  altSecondaryField: $(this).prev().children('[name="miladi_' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]'),
```

```html
In html I have this below:

<div class="form-control has-calender">
  <span>day/month/year</span>
  <input type="hidden" name="jalali_back_date">
  <input type="hidden" name="miladi_back_date">
</div>
<div class="calender" id="back_date"></div>
```

Now the problem is that when I click on first calendar it works but second one changes the value of first! I think the problem is from last part which is:
altField. I think the second time it wants to initialize values it won't! and uses the previous dom element!

Comment: Please edit your question and hit Ctrl+M to bring up the on site editor.  It will allow you to create a working example of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and solve that in this way: there is always one calendar. calendar generate with a function. and will put the date on target input.

```js
function showCalendar(obj) {
  var calendarLength = $(obj).parent().find('div').length;
  var calendarInputId = $(obj).parent().find('input').attr('id');

  if (calendarLength == 0) {
    $('.calendar').remove();

    $(obj).parent('div').append('<div class="calendar"></div>');
    $(".calendar").datepicker({
      altField: "#" + calendarInputId,
      date: "2018-04-16"
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.calendar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3">
  <div class="input-group">
    <button class="input-group-addon" style="position: relative;" onclick="showCalendar(this)">
             cal
         </button>
    <input id="date1" type="text" name="date1" class="form-control" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-3">
  <div class="input-group">
    <button class="input-group-addon" style="position: relative;" onclick="showCalendar(this)">
             cal
         </button>
    <input id="date_nth" type="text" name="date_nth" class="form-control" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon">
  </div>
</div>
```